# Why is mock created by PyMock considered False for assert?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-2.7, assert, pymock

Let's consider this example:

```
class First:
    def register(self, handler):
        pass

class Second:
    def __init__(self, first):
        assert first
        self.__first = first
```

And test injecting mock:

```
class TestSecond(PyMockTestCase):
    def test_construction(self):
        first = self.mock()
        sut = Second(first)
```

This test fails because `first` does not pass the assertion. If I modify my `Second` class to test for `None`, the test will pass:

```
class Second:
    def __init__(self, first):
        assert first is not None
        self.__first = first
```

What causes mock to be recognized as `False`?